# Make a modalbox take up entire screen not only the iframe it sits in

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that has width 962px and height 1335px. Inside this iframe I have a call to a modalbox which pops up when you want to export to excel. But this modalbox which has an grey transparent background which blocks clicks now only sits inside the iframe. I want it to fill the whole screen and not only the iframe.

Is it possible to make the modalbox sit ontop of the iframe, even if the call to the modalbox happens inside the iframe?

Comment: You cannot make the modal fill the whole screen if it is in an iframe. The modal can never expand beyond the borders of the iframe. You can however trigger functions on the page that implements the iframe. And trigger a modal on there covering the whole screen.